# Creating subfolders recursively in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, cmd

I have a variable called `TEXT`  and what I want to achieve is to write a `.bat` script that will create folders with using the characters of `TEXT` and repeat this recursively to a certain depth. For instance let's assume [image]that depth is `1` and `TEXT` equals to `HI` I need this batch script to create two folders named as `H` and `I` and under those folders there should reside also two subfolders names as `H` and `I`.  Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: `CMD.exe` is not my favourite place to experiment recursion. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Whilst you may not wish to experiment, the idea of this site is that you ask for help with your code, not ask for code. Please make some attempts at coding this then update your question with that code when you can go no further.

Comment: This is not some sort of homework or etc. and I don't need to practice recursion in `CMD.exe` I have been programming for more than 10 years and the last thing I really need is re-inventing wheel in an archaic shell. If you know how to write recursive functions in `CMD.exe` you could just teach me and I'd be grateful and others could benefit reading here later. If you don't know it please keep your "programming moral" to yourself.

Comment: I made no suggestion that this was some sort of homework, but if you are looking for someone to teach outside of a teaching environment it is technically homework. It's not programming moral, its how this site works, I'm sorry if you are unable to accept that helpers prefer that askers make some effort too.

Comment: recursively using [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) a subroutine would be the way to go (at least to a certain depth). (if you are not familiar with `cmd`: [pushd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [popd](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) would be useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you did not show any own efforts, I decided to provide a script, because the task is nice:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_TEXT=%~1"   & rem // (take text from first (quoted) command line argument)
set /A "_DEPTH=2" & rem // (number of directory levels to create)
set "_DEBUG=#"    & rem // (set to non-empty value to display directories)

rem // Gather TAB character:
for /F "delims=" %%C in ('
    forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo/0x09"
') do set "_TAB=%%C"

rem // Initialise global variables:
set "$STR= "
set /A "$DEPTH=0"

rem // Check against global wild-cards and other forbidden characters:
set "_TEXT=%_TEXT:"=%" & rem (remove all " characters)
if not defined _TEXT exit /B
if not "%_TEXT:**=%"=="%_TEXT%" mkdir "|" & exit /B
if not "%_TEXT:*?=%"=="%_TEXT%" mkdir "|" & exit /B
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%J in ("%_TAB%" " " "." ":" "/" "\" "<" ">" "|") do (
    if not "!_TEXT:%%~J=!"=="!_TEXT!" mkdir "|" & exit /B
)
endlocal & rem (\ escapes " and deranges syntax highlighting)

rem /* Insert a space in between each adjacent characters of the input text, and
rem    put quotation marks around each of the characters then: */
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%C in ('cmd /U /V /C echo^(^!_TEXT^!^| find /V ""') do (
    set "CHAR=%%C"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "delims=" %%D in (^"!$STR!"!CHAR!" ^") do endlocal & set "$STR=%%D"
)

rem // Call recursive sub-routine for processing:
call :SUB

endlocal
exit /B


:SUB
if %$DEPTH% LSS %_DEPTH% (
    set /A "$DEPTH+=1"
    for %%I in (%$STR%) do (
        if defined _DEBUG (
            set "#DIR=%%~fI"
            call echo %%$DEPTH%%%%_TAB%%%%#DIR%%
        )
        mkdir "%%~I" & (
            pushd "%%~I" && (
                call :SUB
                popd
            )
        )
    )
    set /A "$DEPTH-=1"
)
exit /B
```

Comment: Your script does nothing under `wineconsole cmd` just FYI. Many thanks for the great effort though.